# Notification in Kitkat

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am creating a notification upon click I am asking it cancel a service. It just works fine below 4.4 (Kitkat). My app supports 2.2 (API 8 onwards)

On Kitkit (Nexus 5) The service isn't called at all. I am not where I am going wrong here? It just works fine even on version 4.3?

Here is what I have tried and working on every phone except Nexus 5(Kitkat)

```
createNotification("Click here to cancel notification!", "TestApp");
```

I am calling the above immediately after calling a particular service.

```
private void createNotification(String body,String title) 
{
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int unique_id = 007;

    Intent nintent = new Intent(this,ServicetocancelAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pin = PendingIntent.getService(this,0, nintent, 0);

    //set notify image
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body,java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());

    n.contentIntent = pin;
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pin);

    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    nm.notify(unique_id, n);
}
```

Can somebody help me out fixing this issue with KITKAT?

**Update:**

I tried the following:

```
   Notification("Message", "This is Android Notification Message");
```

And Method

```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void Notification(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage)
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    android.app.Notification notification = new android.app.Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "A New Message",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TransparentActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(10001, notification);
}
```

This piece of code works fine on debug mode but if Export the apk and install it. It just doesn't work at all. It doesn't get to the new activity. I am not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Same problem here. I'm realizing now that it's kitkat. notification intents to launch activities with `PendingIntent` "just work" on versions down to API 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by trying the following code:

```
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= 16)
        {
            Context context = RepeatService.this;

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ServicetocancelAlarm.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Resources res = context.getResources();
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.ticker))
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.cancelText));
            Notification n = builder.build();

            nm.notify(007, n);
        }
```

Else part has the usual notification code that just works fine below API 16..

try it out!!